# use javascript to dislay a form field as text until clicked on

Tags: javascript, forms

I have got this working with the start point as a span, but I want to have the form still function if javascript is disabled in the browser [this is how I had it working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6814062/using-javascript-to-change-some-text-into-an-input-field-when-clicked-on) originally. I'm still very new to javascript, can someone lend a hand please.

```
window.onload = function() {

  document.getElementById('container').onclick = function(event) {
var span, input, text;

// Get the event (handle MS difference)
event = event || window.event;

// Get the root element of the event (handle MS difference)
span = event.target || event.srcElement;

// If it's a span...
if (span && span.tagName.toUpperCase() === "SPAN") {
  // Hide it
  span.style.display = "none";

  // Get its text
  text = span.innerHTML;

  // Create an input
  input = document.createElement("input");
  input.type = "text";
  input.size = Math.max(text.length / 4 * 3, 4);
  span.parentNode.insertBefore(input, span);

  // Focus it, hook blur to undo
  input.focus();
  input.onblur = function() {
    // Remove the input
    span.parentNode.removeChild(input);

    // Update the span
    span.innerHTML = input.value;

    // Show the span again
    span.style.display = "";
      };
    }
  };
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Best way to do this would be to show the input first, then quickly swap it out when the page loads, then swap it back when the user clicks.

You might also consider using the form element the whole time, but just changing CSS classes on it to make it look like normal text.  This would make your UI cleaner and easier to maintain in the future.

Answer (score 0):

use the `readonly` attribute in the `input` elements:

```
<input type="text" readonly />
```

And then remove that attribute with JavaScript in the onclick event handler, reassigning it on `blur`:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

for (i=0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    inputs[i].setAttribute('readonly',true);
    inputs[i].onclick = function(){
        this.removeAttribute('readonly');
    };
    inputs[i].onblur = function(){
        this.setAttribute('readonly',true);
    };
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/L9dD8/2/).

Comment: unless i'm missing something, this would make the form useless if javascript was disabled

Comment: @Philbert: Oops. I've corrected the JavaScript, so the `readonly` is applied, removed, and re-applied by JavaScript, and not set in the HTML. You were right, though, initially this answer would've been non-JS unfriendly...oops. =/

Comment: I'm stll not having much luck with that. [this is my test page](http://pastebin.com/gJWEdPNq) can I get an idiot check please, it's late here.

Comment: I just see the input fields, they don't change.

Answer (score 0):

Then just put the input fields there from the start, and hide them with a script that runs when the form has loaded. That way all the fields will be visible if Javascript is not supported.

Comment: that's what I want to do, but don't really know how, the codeblock above was written by someone else, I have been trying to work it backwards but without any luck

Answer (score 0):

I think your best option would be to wrap a form with `noscript` tags which will fire when Javascript is disabled in a browser. If they display even while in the `noscript` tags then just set them as not visible with Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

if you have jQuery, something like this should work.

```
function makeElementIntoClickableText(elm){
  $(elm).parent().append("<div onClick='switchToInput(this);'>"+ elm.value +"</div>");
  $(elm).hide();
}

function switchToInput(elm){
    $(elm).prev().prev().show();
    $(elm).hide();
}

makeElementIntoClickableText($("input")[0]);
```