# convert text to editable text input and save into db - Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm currently implementing a feature that somebody can add addresses on my page. He can do this via a simple form. What I have now (to print the addresses) is:

```
@foreach($addresses as $address)
                        @if($address->typeOfAddress==0)
                            Name: {{$address->name}}<br/>
                            Straße: {{$address->street}}<br/>
                            PLZ: {{$address->plz}}<br/>
                            Ort: {{$address->city}}<br/>
                            <a type="button" class="btn btn-info" href="/editAddress/{{$address->id}}">Bearbeiten</a>
                            <a type="button" class="btn btn-danger deleteAddressButton" href="/deleteAddress/{{$address->id}}">Löschen</a>
                            <br/><br/>
                            @endif
                    @endforeach
```

The variable `addresses` is passed into the view from the controller.

What I'm trying to achieve now, is that the user can simply click on one of those address parts, like name, straße, plz and ort, and it's converted to an input field, so the value can be changed. Then, when leaving the focus (so clicking somewhere else (or maybe add a save button next to it)), the new data has to be sent to the controller by ajax (the request itself should be no problem then). But: How can I convert it to an input field and how can I then convert it back and react to it (to then send the ajax request)?

I searched in the internet, but didn't find something...

**Edit:** found a fiddle here (http://jsfiddle.net/yXcZG/3) that does nearly what I want, but I have the problem, that it doesn't seem to keep the format, 1. it has much more space between the lines and: when clicking on it to edit, the input field jumps to the bottom of the page and doesn't stay on the same position. Also I just want the variables to be editable, not the text before the `:`.
So this is what I tried: (of course the AJAX thing is still missing, but first the other thing has to work)

```
In JS:

 $(document).on('click', '.editableText', function (e) {
            console.log(this);
            TBox(this);
        });

        $("input").live('blur', function (e) {
            RBox(this);
        });
        function TBox(obj) {
            var id = $(obj).attr("id");
            var input = $('<input />', { 'type': 'text', 'id': id, 'class': 'editableText', 'value': $(obj).html() });
            $(obj).parent().append(input);
            $(obj).remove();
            input.focus();
        }
        function RBox(obj) {
            var id = $(obj).attr("id");
            var input = $('<p />', { 'id': id, 'class': 'editableText', 'html': $(obj).val() });
            $(obj).parent().append(input);
            $(obj).remove();
        }
```

HTML:

```
 @foreach($addresses as $address)
                        @if($address->typeOfAddress==0)
                            Name: <span id="addressName{{$address->id}}" class="editableText">{{$address->name}}</span><br/>
                            Straße: <span id="addressStreet{{$address->id}}" class="editableText">{{$address->street}}</span><br/>
                            PLZ: <span id="addressPLZ{{$address->id}}" class="editableText">{{$address->plz}}</span><br/>
                            Ort: <span id="addressCity{{$address->id}}" class="editableText">{{$address->city}}</span><br/>
                            <a type="button" class="btn btn-danger deleteAddressButton" href="/deleteAddress/{{$address->id}}">Löschen</a>
                            <br/><br/>
                            @endif
                    @endforeach
```

**Edit2:** Found this answer on stackoverflow too (https://stackoverflow.com/a/6814092/3375021), so use contenteditable, but I have the problem, that I on blur neither know, which address should be changed in the database, nor which part of the address..

Comment: Why not load the data into a form and then have an update button? Implement resourceful routes.

Comment: @DenisPriebe Don't want to have that many forms on one page, because there are many addresses on one page... So I only want to show a form when the user presses a button to make a new address, but if he wants to edit one, he should just press on one part of the address, it should be converted to an input and then saved when leaving focus...

Comment: **that it doesn't seem to keep the format** what do you mean with format?

Comment: @JoseRojas exactly the 2 points I wrote after it, there's much more space between the lines and the input jumps to the bottom of the page

Comment: Please update your question what you have done so far, Could be a problem of style

Comment: @JoseRojas I edited my question to represent the things I've tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for a jQuery working solution you can go with this

[JsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/afik162534/hj7880ze/)

You have a listener for when you click an element that is editable, it'll take the value of it and put it inside an input.
After you blur you can take this value and do whatever you want with it..

Here is the javascript (jQuery) part.

```
$(function(){

  $('body').on("click", ".changeable", function(e){

    var text = $(this).text();

    $(this).html("<input type='text' class='input-editable' value='" + text + "'>");

    $(this).find('input').focus();
  });

  $('body').on("blur", ".input-editable", function(e){

    var text = $(this).val();

    $(this).parent().html(text);

   console.log("Value changes to: " + text);
  });

});
```

Comment: @nameless with this one you have the text on blur event and you can do any ajax call within this function to modify your DB. This is what you where looking for, right?

Comment: Yes, you're right, thats exactly what I wanted. And it's better then the other 2 solutions but theres one issue: Clicking on the text 2 times, so the first time converting it to an input, the second time clicking just for fun / basically because you often click on it to make sure the cursor blinks there or just to edit something on the very end or the beginning of the text theres a problem (what a long sentence): the text disappears the second I time I click on...How can I fix that?

Comment: @nameless I've updated the [JsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/afik162534/hj7880ze/1/) , Please mark my answer if it works well for you, Good Luck :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be using `<?php echo $variable; ?>` instead of blade `{{$variabl}}`

If you going to store a html tags or js into your database then you need to not use blade to echo it, you should use php simple echo function instead